# Which version of Chrome includes Journeys?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

There have been a slew of news articles today about the [release of Journeys in Chrome](https://www.theverge.com/2022/2/8/22923323/google-chrome-journeys-revisit-old-browsing-sessions).  I'm running Chrome `98.0.4758.80 (Official Build) (x86_64)` on a Mac, but I don't see this feature included. It looks like I have the latest update.  What version of Chrome do I need to have the Journeys feature included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on the latest version, Chrome Journeys should be present. However, it is possible that it is not yet enabled by default (it was not enabled on mine). Do the following to enable it:

- On the address bar, type `chrome://flags`.
- On the search box, type `journey`.
- Set History Journeys to Enable. Optionally you can also enable History Journey Omnibox action.
- Restart Chrome for the change to take effect.

**Before enabling History Journey**

[image]

[image]

**After enabling History Journey**

[image]

[image]